# How to encrypt unicode character and save to a file?

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone tell me how to encode string and save using vb.net code? sound don't understand, right? let's say i want to save my string(contain unicode) to file like in NOTEPAD when you write unicode and save, you have to choose encoding = Unicode in order to see the same character when you open it later. I want to do this can any one tell me(i need code to encrypt string)?

thanks in advance

makara

Comment: You need to encode or encrypt?

Comment: the answer of Scott Weinstein is what i need.

Comment: Note that encryption is something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you need, or did I misunderstand the question?

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\foo.txt", 
                  "my string with unicode chars Ω", 
                  System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
```